# How to use Paratest globally with the PHAR version of Composer?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

As I said in the title, I use the **PHAR** version of **PHPUnit 10.0.18** and I have installed **Paratest 7.1.2** *globally* via Composer.
I am launching it via **PhpStorm 2022.3.3**.

I use an XML configuration file and a custom bootstrap that contains a custom autoloader for my own framework.

I get :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Missing path to '/phpunit' in /home/lionel/.config/composer/vendor/brianium/paratest/src/Util/PhpstormHelper.php:57

I tried (temporarily, just to see if it works) to replace in the file `~/.config/composer/vendor/brianium/paratest/src/Util/PhpstormHelper.php` the line :

```php
$phpunitKey = self::getArgvKeyFor($argv, '/phpunit');
```

by

```php
$phpunitKey = self::getArgvKeyFor($argv, '/var/www/html/lib/phpunit.phar');
```

but then I got :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "phpunit\framework\TestCase" not found in /var/www/html/perso/otra/tests/src/BlocksTest.php:13

Error that I didn't get without the use of Paratest.

---

**EDIT**
Paratest said to me that they...

> only support PHPUnit installed by composer
> ...oO

Comment: A PhpStorm team member here. It looks like a Paratest issue, so it makes sense to submit this to [their tracker](https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest/issues)

Comment: Ok, I just created a ticket to their tracker https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest/issues/747.